# TypeError: non_max_suppression() got an unexpected keyword argument 'score_threshold'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Hi I am using win 7 64 bit and tensorflow version 1.5 I've tried 1.9 and higher but isnt work and I've tried tensorflow-gpu version but again isnt work all the error this

Comment: Hello, can you provide the snippet of code calling tf.non_max_supression() and the types/shapes of the arguments you give it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same issue using tf 1.8. Tensorflow versions < 1.9 did not support the `score_threshold` param.
Need to be sure you're using version 1.9 or newer.